# Simple Commerce cyrillic characters turned in question marks in PayPal

Tags: paypal, character-encoding, simple-commerce

I have a Russian website where in the head section I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In Simple Commerse template I have included `country_code="RU"`  parameter but in PayPal page the titles turn into question marks.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?